# The orgstruct-mode seems to be gone from the org-plus-contrib

Tags: org-mode

I've been using orgstruct in my message mode hooks but it seems it is gone now in the 20181230 org ELPA package.

```
(add-hook 'message-mode-hook 'turn-on-orgstruct)
(add-hook 'message-mode-hook 'turn-on-orgstruct++)
```

as described in the Org-mode info https://orgmode.org/manual/Orgstruct-mode.html are not working anymore.  Does somebody know what happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OrgStruct is gone in org-mode 9.2. I guess this applies to the ELPA package version you mention as well.

https://orgmode.org/Changes.html

> **Removal of OrgStruct mode mode and radio lists**
>
> OrgStruct minor mode and radio lists mechanism (org-list-send-list and org-list-radio-lists-templates) are removed from the code base.
>
> Note that only radio lists have been removed, not radio tables.
>
> If you want to manipulate lists like in Org in other modes, we suggest to use orgalist.el, which you can install from GNU ELPA.
>
> If you want to use Org folding outside of Org buffers, you can have a look at the outshine package in the MELPA repository.

The rationale for the removal according to [this mailing list thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-08/msg00482.html) was basically: it was broken, hackish, made org-mode development harder, and there are alternatives.